# Combine two properties in one with RxJS

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm working on http response in angular framework that I need to combine two properties into one with rxjs.

Imagine we have such a response from API, and now I need to combine the **age** with **birthday**. It's an HTTP response that is an observable naturally, so I need to change the result before subscribing on it.

```js
{
  "pagination": {
    "totalPages": 1,
    "totalItems": 4,
    "count": 4,
    "itemsPerPage": 20,
    "page": 1
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "key": "value",
      "key": "value",
      "tessst": {
        "key": "value",
        "key": "value",
        "key": "value",
        "birthday": "1940-09-23T00:00:00+00:00",
        "age": "34",
        "key": {
          "key": "value",
          "key": "value"
        },
        "key": "value",
        "key": {
          "key": "value",
          "key": "value"
        }
      },
      "key": {
        "key": "value",
        "key": "value",
        "key": "value"
      },
      "key": "value"
    },
```

So at the end I need something like this, I also remove unnecessary code but the rest of the object is like the previous one except the **birtday**.

```js
{
  "pagination": {
    "totalPages": 1,
    "totalItems": 4,
    "count": 4,
    "itemsPerPage": 20,
    "page": 1
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "tessst": {
        "birthday": {
             birthdayDateTime: "1940-09-23T00:00:00+00:00",
             age: 34
        }, 
      },
    },
```

Comment: This is a paginated payload, do you need to also keep information about paging, or only extract the age and birthday from these entries?

Comment: @siavashbashiri please share how the expected output should look like

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu I need to keep the whole data + the new birthday property that includes age too and they will be just a property, and I need the whole data since it's for a data table so I need the paging info too.

Comment: I currently don't understand how this is related to RxJS or Angular. It seems to be a issue of modify an object, i.e. having one object as input and another as output. To me it appears to be irrelevant where the object came from or what you do with the result. Did I misunderstand your issue?

Comment: Dear @churill, I explained that the result comes from an HTTP call that actually is observable, so I need to change the data before subscribing to it.

Comment: @churill I Updated the explanation of the post since it wasn't clear for you and the others may be and I also tried to simplify the explantion so please tell me if it's not clear for you.

Comment: @siavashbashiri Yes, thanks, it's clearer now. Which RxJS-operators do you know that can transform an object? I believe that should be your main question and the point you need to research.

Comment: @churill I think the map operator can help but I don't know how to use it in this case.

Comment: @siavashbashiri Correct. Do you have a function that does the transformation? You can simply pass it to map `getFromApi().pipe(map(model => myTransformFunction(model))).subscrine(transformedModel => ....)`

Comment: why not just calculate the age from the date when you need it? or if you really need it create new object from the json with the data you need.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can try this logic. I have written in (**TypeScript**) :

```js
let obj: any = {
  pagination: {
    totalPages: 1,
    totalItems: 4,
    count: 4,
    itemsPerPage: 20,
    page: 1,
  },
  data: [
    {
      key: 'value',
      tessst: {
        key: 'value',

        birthday: '1940-09-23T00:00:00+00:00',
        age: '34',

        key2: {
          key: 'value',
        },
        key3: 'value',
        key4: {
          key: 'value',
        },
      },
      key5: {
        key: 'value',
      },
      key6: 'value',
    },

    {
      key: 'value',
      tessst: {
        key: 'value',

        birthday: '1942-09-23T00:00:00+00:00',
        age: '36',

        key2: {
          key: 'value',
        },
        key3: 'value',
        key4: {
          key: 'value',
        },
      },
      key5: {
        key: 'value',
      },
      key6: 'value',
    },
  ],
};



//

of(obj.data)
      .pipe(
        map((x) => {
          return x.map((e: any) => e.tessst);
        }),
        map((x) => {
          return x.map((e: any) => {
            let temp = {
              birthday: e.birthday,
              age: e.age,
            };

            delete e.birthday;
            delete e.age;

            e.birthday = temp;

            return e;
          });
        })
      )
      .subscribe((x) => console.log(x));
```